# Deserializing individual objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Is there a way in .Net 4 to easily deserialize a stream of mixed objects one by one? I can read to the start of the element for an object I want to deserialize using XmlTextReader.Read(), but have tried many ways to deserialize that specific object unsuccessfully.

The types I want to deserialize can be read as a list of those types without a problem using XmlSerializer, however I want to be able to mix them rather than having input files containing just lists of one object type.

e.g.

```
<Objects>
  <TypeA>...</TypeA>
  <TypeB>...</TypeB>
  <TypeA>...</TypeA>
  <TypeC>...</TypeC>
  ...
</Objects>
```

The ordering of the objects in  would be random.

Many thanks for any pointers.

I've looked at XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer and XElement, but could not get them to work for this (although I possibly didn't set those up correctly as I'm not very familiar with them).

Comment: Do you need to deserialize all of the individual items at once? It's not clear why you say you want to do it one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the XmlSerializer.

However, be careful with the following:

1. The array you are serializing/deserializing must be declared as an array of "object" (or the base object if all other types inherit from it)
2. Each type will have "xsi:type" attached to it
3. You must use [XmlInclude] to include all the type(s) you are ever going to need with the "root" object.

The need to [XmlInclude] all the object types mean that you're not going to be able to dynamically add types to the serialization.   You'll need to add [XmlInclude]'s and recompile to include the new type(s).

Your XML, however, will become:

```
<Objects>
  <TypeObj xsi:type="TypeA">...</TypeObj>
  <TypeObj xsi:type="TypeB">...</TypeObj>
  <TypeObj xsi:type="TypeA">...</TypeObj>
  <TypeObj xsi:type="TypeC">...</TypeObj>
      :
</Objects>
```

This is the most flexible and "normal" way of approach XML serialization of multiple types.  However, if you need to keep your exact format, you can declare your class this way:

```
[XmlRoot("Objects")]
public class Objects
{
    [XmlElement("TypeA")] public TypeA[] TypeAObjects;
    [XmlElement("TypeB")] public TypeB[] TypeBObjects;
    [XmlElement("TypeC")] public TypeC[] TypeCObjects;
         :
}
```

`[XmlElement]` means that all the objects are jumbled up on the same level (different from `XmlArray`). They do not even have to be in order.

The pitfalls of doing this, however, is that if you want to add a new type, you'll have to modify the "Objects" class.

Comment: Thanks for the XmlInclude tip. Wasn't aware of that. Whilst using XmlInclude would make XmlSerializer aware of the type, it doesn't help with deserializing one object at a time (I probably didn't call that out loudly enough in my question though) as I can't see a way for XmlSerializer to do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Scott McKay, XmlInclude is used for exactly this purpose.  On serialization, it takes an "object" (of any type) and serialize to an element with a "xsi:type" attribute.  On deserialization, it takes that element, reads the type attribute, and re-creates the type.  All automatic.  This is exactly what you need, unless I have misinterpreted your question!  :-)

Comment: @Scott McKay, so in other words, just shuff the entire XML array into deserialization.  However, your XML is going to look a bit different from your original style: `<Objects><TypeObj xsi:type="TypeA">...</TypeObj><TypeObj xsi:type="TypeB">...</TypeObj></Objects>`

Comment: @Scott McKay, if you want to keep your original style, there is a much simpler way.  Just declare TypeA, TypeB, etc. as different properties of arrays of different types in your objects class, mark them all as [XmlElement] (so that they all jumble together in the same level).  XmlSerializer will make sure each goes into the appropriate property, regardless of their order.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but it might be an idea to take a look at how RestSharp does their deserialization. https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp

Specifilcally Take a look at RestSharp/Deserializers/XmlDeserializer.cs

Comment: Will do. In the meantime, I finally got _something_ to work. It doesn't strike me as overly elegant, but seems to work. I'd love to know if there's a better way.

Comment: XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", null);
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");
            dcs.WriteObject(writer, new A());
            dcs.WriteObject(writer, new B());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Close();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.xml");
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(sr);
            // skip header and root
            reader.Read();
            reader.Read();

            while ((obj = dcs.ReadObject(reader)) != null)
            {
                ....
            }

Comment: Missed an important piece.

            List<Type> knownTypes = new List<Type>();
            knownTypes.Add(typeof(A));
            knownTypes.Add(typeof(B));

            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(object), knownTypes);

Comment: @Scott McKay, try the XMLSerializer with [XmlInclude] of known types.  It should be easier than the DataContractSerializer since DCS is opt-in while XMLS is opt-out.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an `XmlSerializer` for each type. How many types you have and how many times each would get used would determine if it's better to create a new `XmlSerializer` for each object as you process it, or store them in a `Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer>` to be reused. The `XmlSerializer` takes the `type` in its constructor, and then you can call the `Deserialize` method, passing it a `StringReader` that contains the XML string you read from your file. Hopefully that's enough to get you started, but if you need more help I can throw together some sample code ;)